# Instagram oAuth Redirects to Application in iOS

Tags: javascript, angular, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have integrated instagram oAuth app using javascript in my project. however in iOS when we do oAuth from IG it will redirect to the Instagram application, somehow I want to stop it and it will be open on the browser.

I am using the below code to do the oAuth from IG.

```
window.open(`https://api.instagram.com/accounts/logoutin/?force_classic_login=&next=${encodeURIComponent(`/oauth/authorize/?response_type=code&scope=user_profile,user_media&client_id=${environment.ig_client_id}&redirect_uri=${R_URL}`)}`,'_self');
```

Comment: Not sure why you are forcing this to go via the `/accounts/logoutin/` endpoint first. What happens when you actually implement this the way the documentation says you should? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions#step-1--get-authorization

Comment: we want to force logout from logged-in users that's why using it. suggest it, if there is any other way to do it?